# IPython nbconvert citations issue

Tags: latex, ipython, jupyter-notebook, biblatex

I'm trying to use citations in IPython. I'm having some isssues.

My notebook has one markdown cell,

```
<cite data-cite="debreu_theory_1959">(Debreu, 1959)</cite>
```

My template looks like this:

```
((*- extends 'article.tplx' -*))

((* block bibliography *))
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{bibliography}
((* endblock bibliography *))
```

And my bibliography has the section

```
@book{debreu_theory_1959,
  address = {New Haven, {CT}},
  title = {Theory of value: An axiomatic analysis of economic equilibrium},
  shorttitle = {Theory of value},
  url = {http://books.google.com/books?hl=en\&lr=\&id=QkX10epC46cC\&oi=fnd\&pg=PA1\&dq=debreau+theory+of+value\&ots=9DNz2653qg\&sig=fKS1CYQ6ZFmXIUmOgDq3DRLPEmQ},
  timestamp = {2014-04-17 14:32:20},
  number = {17},
  urldate = {2014-04-17},
  publisher = {Yale University Press},
  author = {Debreu, Gerard},
  year = {1959},
  file = {Snapshot:/home/haldane/.mozilla/firefox/8qzu92vh.default/zotero/storage/CIEI6RPS/books.html:text/html}
}
```

My command line call is

```
ipython3 nbconvert --to pdf bibliography.ipynb --template bibliography
```

The pdf is created, but all it contains is

```
[?]
```

Yes, bibliography.ipynb, bibliography.tplx, and bibliography.bib are all in the same folder.